# Raspberry Pi Camera

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, camera, raspicam, amazon

I have purchased an [Imported 1.3 5MP Webcam Video Camera Module Board 1080p 720p Fast for Raspberry Pi 2](http://www.amazon.in/Webcam-Video-Camera-Module-Raspberry/dp/B01GECZE9O/ref=sr_1_17?ie=UTF8&qid=1493199763&sr=8-17&keywords=raspberry%20pi%20camera). On testing this particular camera on Iceweasel/Firefox, the camera quality was absolutely fine; doing the same on chromium the video gets disrupted and pixelated.Even on using a normal USB camera with chromium, everything worked fine. Can someone suggest solutions for improving video feed on chromium using the raspberry pi camera or any compatible hardware? [No USB Camera]

Board: Raspberry Pi 2 B+
OS: Raspbian Jessie

Comment: This is a [known issue in chromium](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1498) - there's a hack mentioned at the end of that ticket but it's worth reading the thread to understand what's going on (short version: chromium doesn't like cameras that don't list a simple discrete set of resolutions)

Comment: @DaveJones by hack did you mean this?

sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 gst_v4l2src_is_broken=1

If yes? Please elaborate how to implement this hack.

Comment: Any other compatible camera (with chromium) that you can suggest?

Comment: Yeah, that's the hack I meant - the associated thread goes into some more detail on the chromium issue itself. As for other cameras, I would assume most USB cameras work: they mostly list a trivial set of discrete resolutions, unlike the Pi's camera which (having a full ISP at its disposal) effectively says "I support *any* resolution you want"

Comment: @DaveJones I ran this command "sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 gst_v4l2src_is_broken=1" but nothing happens!

Comment: @DaveJones 

I ran this command "sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 gst_v4l2src_is_broken=1" but nothing happens!

Comment: Oh well, guess that workaround isn't applicable for this particular case (it is meant to fix something different, so that's not entirely surprising). In which case: use another camera, another browser, or try and persuade chromium upstream to fix their V4L2 bugs

Comment: @DaveJones Any other compatible cameras you can suggest that works fine with chromium? [Not USB ones only onboard].

Comment: The onboard cameras all use the same firmware so it won't make any difference what camera you plug into the CSI port: you'll wind up with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply run the following commands to enable and configure the module:

```
echo "bcm2835-v4l2" | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/bcm2835-v4l2.conf > /dev/null
echo "options bcm2835-v4l2 gst_v4l2src_is_broken=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/bcm2835-v4l2.conf > /dev/null
```

Then reboot your pi:

```
sudo reboot
```

And everything should work like a charm ;)